# Were the barn scenes in Transformers: Age of Extinction and Astronaut Farmer filmed at the same location?

Tags: film-location, transformers, age-of-extinction, astronaut-farmer

Wondering if two scenes were filmed in the same place...

I just saw *Transformers: Age of Extinction* and was struck by the barn where Mark Wahlberg's character does his tinkering.

It instantly made me think of the barn where Billy Bob Thornton's character built his rocket in *Astronaut Farmer*.

Does anyone have information regarding these locations and whether it is the same barn? I'm not sure about the outside, but the inside seemed very familiar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't appear that they were filmed at the same place.

**Astronaut Farmer** was filmed in New Mexico, at the [Bonanza Creek Ranch](http://www.bonanzacreekranch.com/docs/Movie-Credits.pdf):

[image].

Other films shot here include:

- Cowboys and Aliens
- Appaloosa
- 3:10 to Yuma

Transformers on the other hand [doesn't credit the Ranch](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2109248/locations). Whilst I can't find the exact location it's barn was filmed in, it doesn't appear to have done any filming in New Mexico.